# Form load interface

Tags: c#, winforms

In my form_load I have a mysql connection that loads data in a datagrid, when starting my application it will first try to load the mysql database and after its done it will load the form/interface with all the controls.

This leaves the user the impression nothing is happening, how can I first load the form/interface with all the controls and then my mysql database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say, 3 approaches

1 - Separate Splash screen

2 - On-Form "splash screen" - first thing you do on `form.load`, is `Me.Show()`, then show a message, something like "Please wait while data is loaded". Progress can be shown to users as well using `Application.DoEvents` which will refresh your screen.

3 - Background worker thread. Using it, you can actually give user progress updates. That will leave your form completely responsive. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Move your code to `Shown` event or `OnShown` overridden method. this will allow your form shown to user before it loads grid.

You should move your "Database calls" to worker threads as well.

```
protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e)
{
    //Delegate the DB calls to worker threads here 
    //everything will be smooth then..
    base.OnShown(e);
}
```

Comment: This is issue of busy thread because of DB, not when form shows

Comment: @T.S. Of course, but moving the code to `OnShown` will make form to appear then does the work.

Comment: @T.S. Not sure it is your down-vote, but this answer doesn't deserve it.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to approach this situation. You need to pick the approach that best suits your needs.

Approach 1: Create a splash screen. A splash screen is a small window that opens up and usually had product info and a message like "Initializing...". You can see this in a lot of applications, such as Microsoft Office. You can see how to make one by looking at [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5454/A-Pretty-Good-Splash-Screen-in-C).

Approach 2: You will need to make your load data happen in a separate thread then your UI. You will need to load your data in the separate thread and bind it to a list of some sort temporarily, then after its done, bind the list to your Datagrid

Answer (score 0):

Use other thread for loading data from mysql. It's loading form first, but not displaying it until code has finished work.

```
new Thread(new ThreadStart(LoadDataMethodHere)).Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Form Shown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.shown.aspx) event.

Alternatively you can use a different thread to connect to database and show data or use a timer.